# Dask worker graceful task failure

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When I run dask.distributed workers, any exception thrown in the task function gets propagated to scheduler and kills whole job. Is there a way to gracefully fail the task so that scheduler takes care of retrying it (potentially on another worker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Dask.distributed scheduler interprets an exception as the true value of the task.  Automatic retries are not currently supported (as of August 2017).  However this has been frequently requested.  I would not be surprised to see this change in the near future.

In the mean time we recommend adding retry logic within your task.

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    for i in range(n_retries):
        try:
            # your code
            # return result
        except Exception:
            pass

future = client.submit(f, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer. Right, in the absence of such feature we're currently implementing retries inside single worker.

Comment: Can this be used now - https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.retry? If so, can you share an example?

Comment: Or, can we achieve this using client.submit(retries=N)? Also, is there a way to try a failed task on a worker other than where it failed? I am mostly worried about memory overflow exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: The retries keyword is also an excellent choice (it's newer than this answer).

Comment: You can raise the `dask.distributed.Reschedule` exception from within the task and the scheduler will try to send it elsewhere.  That requires logic in your function though.